# How can Telegram Bot get the message text of if you have the message ID?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

So the thought is that a user A replies to a post in a chat from user B using a command `/command`. **How can we get the contents of the message (of user B)?**

Like, we get an `Update update` and I can do

```
String messageText = update.getMessage().getText(); // what user A sent aka "\command" string
long messageId = update.getMessage().getMessageId();
```

But what commands do I use to get the message of user B which is technically inside `update`, right?

Answer (score 1):

As per Telegram docs, [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object received in an Update will contain `reply_to_message` field if the message was sent as a reply to a previous message. The `reply_to_message` is of type `Message` as well, so you can get its text and ID the usual way (via `getText` and `getMessageID`).

I am not sure how this would be done in java (I guess by simple `getReplyToMessage`), this is how I would handle it in javascript.

```
const update = req.body;
const message = update.message || update.edited_message;

if (message.reply_to_message) {
    // this means message was a reply to a previous message
    const previousMessageID = message.reply_to_message.message_id;
    const previousMessageText = message.reply_to_message.text;
    ...
}
```